# How do I access the specific url's entered in a browser using Python3?

Tags: python

I am creating a program on python and I need access to the url's entered/requested by browsers. I have tried making a proxy and listening to all requests made, but I get a lot of requests that are not things I have tried to access from my browser. These requests are things related to other application running on my computer and they are irrelevant to my program. The proxy does catch request's made from my browser but they are CONNECT requests and the url is not specific. I want to be able to get the specific url, as in, https://stackoverflow.com/somepage/anotherpage/and/so/on. I have spent hours trying to configure my proxy better, also tried creating a proxy that connects to the main url(as in: stackoverflow.com) and listen for more specific url's but none of it has worked. I understand that python may not be the best programming language to do this sort of task, so if it is possible in another language(maybe JavaScript) to get the url entered and then pass it to my python program that would be great too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to install a browser driver, e.g. [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).
Then install Selenium; `pip install selenium`.

After that, do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url1 = ''
while True:
    url2 = driver.current_url
    if url2 != url1:
        print(url2)
    url1 = url2
```

And open some websites in the Chrome window the code opened. Their urls will be printed in the terminal.

Comment: I tested out using selenium and your code with the chromedriver, but it only ever printed out "data,." and that was all. I tried opening a bunch of websites and none of them printed out a url. I will do some more research on selenium to see if there is another way to access the url using it. Thanks anyways @DavidDeprost

Comment: You should open the websites in the chrome window that the code opened. Did you try that?

Comment: I tried the program again and now it is working, except it only works in the same window and the same tab as was opened with the program. Do you know of any way to have it work with every tab? @DavidDeprost

Comment: To be honest, this is not something I am experienced with. I had to go look through the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) docs and some other Stackoverflow questions to solve this for you. Maybe this can be helpful: https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903 . Don't forget to accept the best answer!